# Getting External-DNS to work with Ingress Objects in Kops AWS 1.7 K8s Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to figure out how to get this setup to work:

- I am using Kube 1.7 (no RBAC) spun up from kops in AWS
- I have a single nginx ingress controller for my entire cluster that is using a `LoadBalancer` service in the `kube-system`, namespace installed via Helm
- I have `cert-manager` setup in `kube-system`, installed via Helm and
  using `ClusterIssuers`
- I have `external-dns` setup in `kube-system` installed via Helm
- I have multiple applications, one per namespace, with associated `Ingress` objects in each namespace.
- I am annotating the Ingresses with the appropriate annotations for both `cert-manager` (`certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod`) and `external-dns` (`dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: app.contoso.com`)

In this scenario, `cert-manager` is reacting appropriately to the `Ingress` object (modifying it to complete the ACME challenge), but `external-dns` is not doing anything (logs are saying all hostnames are up to date). If I manually add a Route53 record for the ELB associated with the LB service, everything works as expected. Inspecting the Ingress object, I see that the status block looks like so:

```
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

which I suppose is why `external-dns` isn't reacting? How do I get this to work? Per the documentation

More troubleshooting information (pod definitions, ingress definitions, controller logs, etc.) can be found here: https://gist.github.com/DWSR/f6d596850346223393bec23b289c9731

Answer (score 3):

I solved this myself. The nginx ingress controller has a `--publish-service` command line argument which will cause it to update the status fields on the ingress objects which, in turn, will cause `external-dns` to create the appropriate DNS records. When installing via Helm, simply set `.Values.controller.publishService.enabled` to `true` and this will take effect.

Sources:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/cli-arguments.md
- https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress#configuration